# How to populate mysql database column to json values

Tags: mysql, json, database

I try to populate mysql database column values to json values of items without success.

Database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ejkb4_k2_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `catid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `published` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `introtext` mediumtext,
  `fulltext` mediumtext,
  `video` text,
  `gallery` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_fields` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `extra_fields_search` text NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_by_alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `checked_out` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `checked_out_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `publish_up` datetime NOT NULL,
  `publish_down` datetime NOT NULL,
  `trash` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `access` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `featured` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `featured_ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `image_caption` text NOT NULL,
  `image_credits` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `video_caption` text NOT NULL,
  `video_credits` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hits` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `params` text NOT NULL,
  `metadesc` text NOT NULL,
  `metadata` text NOT NULL,
  `metakey` text NOT NULL,
  `plugins` varchar(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'k2storeitem_price=1',
  `code_search` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `language` char(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `item` (`published`,`publish_up`,`publish_down`,`trash`,`access`),
  KEY `catid` (`catid`),
  KEY `created_by` (`created_by`),
  KEY `ordering` (`ordering`),
  KEY `featured` (`featured`),
  KEY `featured_ordering` (`featured_ordering`),
  KEY `hits` (`hits`),
  KEY `language` (`language`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`title`,`introtext`,`fulltext`,`extra_fields_search`,`image_caption`,`image_credits`,`video_caption`,`video_credits`,`metadesc`,`metakey`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=992 ;
```

One item from this database table:

```
INSERT INTO `ejkb4_k2_items` (`id`, `code`, `title`, `alias`, `catid`, `published`, `introtext`, `fulltext`, `video`, `gallery`, `extra_fields`, `extra_fields_search`, `created`, `created_by`, `created_by_alias`, `checked_out`, `checked_out_time`, `modified`, `modified_by`, `publish_up`, `publish_down`, `trash`, `access`, `ordering`, `featured`, `featured_ordering`, `image_caption`, `image_credits`, `video_caption`, `video_credits`, `hits`, `params`, `metadesc`, `metadata`, `metakey`, `plugins`, `code_search`, `language`) VALUES

(992, '1234567', 'Спирателен вентил ХХХ', 'спирателен-вентил-ххх', 704, 1, '<ul>\r\n<li>материал</li>\r\n<li>още нещо</li>\r\n<li>друго...</li>\r\n<li>и още</li>\r\n</ul>', '', '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pMPinbC1VJ4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>', NULL, '[{"id":"1","value":"1\\""},{"id":"9","value":"22311"},{"id":"5","value":""},{"id":"6","value":""},{"id":"7","value":""},{"id":"8","value":""},{"id":"10","value":"\\u041f\\u0440\\u043e\\u0438\\u0437\\u0432\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u0442\\u0435\\u043b \\u0425"}]', '1" 22311     Производител Х ', '2017-05-30 07:27:22', 50, '', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2017-06-06 13:20:35', 50, '2017-05-30 07:27:22', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, '', '', '', '', 14, '{"catItemTitle":"","catItemTitleLinked":"","catItemFeaturedNotice":"","catItemAuthor":"","catItemDateCreated":"","catItemRating":"","catItemImage":"","catItemIntroText":"","catItemExtraFields":"","catItemHits":"","catItemCategory":"","catItemTags":"","catItemAttachments":"","catItemAttachmentsCounter":"","catItemVideo":"","catItemVideoWidth":"","catItemVideoHeight":"","catItemAudioWidth":"","catItemAudioHeight":"","catItemVideoAutoPlay":"","catItemImageGallery":"","catItemImageGalleryWidth":"","catItemImageGalleryHeight":"","catItemDateModified":"","catItemReadMore":"","catItemCommentsAnchor":"","catItemK2Plugins":"","itemDateCreated":"","itemTitle":"","itemFeaturedNotice":"","itemAuthor":"","itemFontResizer":"","itemPrintButton":"","itemEmailButton":"","itemSocialButton":"","itemVideoAnchor":"","itemImageGalleryAnchor":"","itemCommentsAnchor":"","itemRating":"","itemImage":"","itemImgSize":"","itemImageMainCaption":"","itemImageMainCredits":"","itemIntroText":"","itemFullText":"","itemExtraFields":"","itemDateModified":"","itemHits":"","itemCategory":"","itemTags":"","itemAttachments":"","itemAttachmentsCounter":"","itemVideo":"","itemVideoWidth":"","itemVideoHeight":"","itemAudioWidth":"","itemAudioHeight":"","itemVideoAutoPlay":"","itemVideoCaption":"","itemVideoCredits":"","itemImageGallery":"","itemImageGalleryWidth":"","itemImageGalleryHeight":"","itemNavigation":"","itemComments":"","itemTwitterButton":"","itemFacebookButton":"","itemGooglePlusOneButton":"","itemAuthorBlock":"","itemAuthorImage":"","itemAuthorDescription":"","itemAuthorURL":"","itemAuthorEmail":"","itemAuthorLatest":"","itemAuthorLatestLimit":"","itemRelated":"","itemRelatedLimit":"","itemRelatedTitle":"","itemRelatedCategory":"","itemRelatedImageSize":"","itemRelatedIntrotext":"","itemRelatedFulltext":"","itemRelatedAuthor":"","itemRelatedMedia":"","itemRelatedImageGallery":"","itemK2Plugins":""}', '', 'robots=\nauthor=', '', '{"k2storeitem_enabled":"1","k2storeitem_sku":"","k2storeitem_price":"","k2storespecial_price":"","k2storeitem_tax":"0","k2storeitem_shipping":"0","k2storeitem_metrics":{"item_length":"0.00000000","item_width":"0.00000000","item_height":"0.00000000","item_length_class_id":"0","item_weight":"0.00000000","item_weight_class_id":"0"},"k2storeitem_cart_text":""}', '', '*');
```

All values from column `code` must be populated to column extra_fields - as value of id:9. For example {"id":"9","value":"22311"} must going to: {"id":"9","value":"1234567"} in all database items.

Comment: Perhaps the first item to note in your question is that you have defined 38 columns in your table, but have only 24 values to populate into those 38 columns. In the type of insert statement you're using, you have to exactly match the number of columns (field names) and values both in number (need 38 of each) and in order. 

Please add in the code that you're using to do this work along with any error messages you're receiving.

Comment: @Bob Dill, this task is only database task. There is no php code. I need to insert for all items in database only content from "code" column in column "extra_fields" id 9 value.